# installing imblearn on jupyter notebook anaconda

Tags: installation, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, smote, imblearn

I have been trying to install imblearn on jupyter for some time.
I run to the error:

```
!pip install imblearn --ignore-installed scikit-learn

collecting imblearn
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/a7/4179e6ebfd654bd0eac0b9c06125b8b4c96a9d0a8ff9e9507eb2a26d2d7e/imblearn-0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9d/20/0ffe8665a44bce7616bd33d4368a198fecad3b226bcafa38c63ef0f6286f/scikit_learn-1.0.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting imbalanced-learn (from imblearn)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/79/e86c8fd859dca4fb1fbfc61376afc63210177a235a7bfbe7219b02edf8f3/imbalanced_learn-0.9.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 (from scikit-learn)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/cf/6e354304bcb9c6413c4e02a747b600061c21d38ba51e7e544ac7bc66aecc/threadpoolctl-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting joblib>=0.11 (from scikit-learn)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3e/d5/0163eb0cfa0b673aa4fe1cd3ea9d8a81ea0f32e50807b0c295871e4aab2e/joblib-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting scipy>=1.1.0 (from scikit-learn)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/69/4af412d078cef2298f7d90546fa0e03e65a032558bd85319239c72ae0c3c/scipy-1.7.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.14.6 (from scikit-learn)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/9f/da37cc4a188a1d5d203d65ab28d6504e17594b5342e0c1dc5610ee6f4535/numpy-1.21.6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy, scipy, threadpoolctl, joblib, scikit-learn, imbalanced-learn, imblearn
```

i have tried to upgrade my scikit-learn version to 1.1.0 that also returned an error  that this is not availble .
i also tried to run this on the command prompt:

```
(base) C:\Users\agns1>pip install imblearn on anaconda pip install imblearn
Collecting imblearn
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/a7/4179e6ebfd654bd0eac0b9c06125b8b4c96a9d0a8ff9e9507eb2a26d2d7e/imblearn-0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting on
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/8a/a19679d9e009f8eeedce74fdcc252c5a5c834b30f98c4c13a3a93ff92842/on-0.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (47kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 469kB/s
Collecting anaconda
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/81/44690deb604d72ffa59ec6e5552f4ef21afb59c8e2698717c8a6be4af09c/anaconda-0.0.1.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\agns1\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (19.2.3)
Collecting install
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/c8/8cbca135f9e167810756ea2bc34b028501936675fcbd7dadccf752fa4622/install-1.3.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting imbalanced-learn (from imblearn)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/79/e86c8fd859dca4fb1fbfc61376afc63210177a235a7bfbe7219b02edf8f3/imbalanced_learn-0.9.1-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=1.0.0 in c:\users\agns1\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from imbalanced-learn->imblearn) (1.1.0)
Collecting numpy>=1.17.3 (from imbalanced-learn->imblearn)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/9f/da37cc4a188a1d5d203d65ab28d6504e17594b5342e0c1dc5610ee6f4535/numpy-1.21.6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\users\agns1\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from imbalanced-learn->imblearn) (3.1.0)
Collecting scikit-learn>=1.1.0 (from imbalanced-learn->imblearn)
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scikit-learn>=1.1.0 (from imbalanced-learn->imblearn) (from versions: 0.9, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.13, 0.13.1, 0.14, 0.14.1, 0.15.0b1, 0.15.0b2, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16b1, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.17b1, 0.17, 0.17.1, 0.18, 0.18.1, 0.18.2, 0.19b2, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20rc1, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.20.4, 0.21rc2, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.21.2, 0.21.3, 0.22rc2.post1, 0.22rc3, 0.22, 0.22.1, 0.22.2, 0.22.2.post1, 0.23.0rc1, 0.23.0, 0.23.1, 0.23.2, 0.24.dev0, 0.24.0rc1, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.2, 1.0rc1, 1.0rc2, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for scikit-learn>=1.1.0 (from imbalanced-learn->imblearn)

(base) C:\Users\agns1>scikit-learn
    ERROR: imbalanced-learn 0.9.1 has requirement scikit-learn>=1.1.0, but you'll have scikit-learn 1.0.2 which is incompatible.
    ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\agns1\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\.libs\\libopenblas.XWYDX2IKJW2NMTWSFYNGFUWKQU3LYTCZ.gfortran-win_amd64.dll'
    Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

it also returned an error is there any way to install imblearn in order to use the SMOTE from it ?
thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Conda is throwing an environment error that basically says: "you cannot upgrade scikit-learn because you do not have permission to update libopenblas."

The easiest fix would be to create a new environment and install a fresh set of dependencies:

```bash
conda create -y -n imblearn python=3.9
conda activate imblearn
python -m pip install imbalanced-learn
```

Fixing the permission error in the `base` environment is a different matter. Reinstalling conda might be the easiest option. The conda getting started guide should be helpful for these points:

https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html